# separate the string and number from list in android

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, split

i want to split the mProductType is one list and mRetailerid is another list.how can i get it ????

```
public class RetailerNames implements Serializable{


private String mProductType;
private String mRetailerid;

public String getmProductType() {
    return mProductType;
}

public void setmProductType(String mProductType) {
    this.mProductType = mProductType;
}

public String getmRetailerid() {
    return mRetailerid;
}

public void setmRetailerid(String mRetailerid) {
    this.mRetailerid = mRetailerid;
}
@Override
   public String toString() {
    return   mProductType + "," +
            mRetailerid ;  

}
```

I have used below code :

```
    ArrayList<RetailerNames> retailerNamesList = (ArrayList<RetailerNames>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("ProductsDetailsDescriptionPage");
    System.out.println("The retailer details are"+" "+retailerNamesList);
```

Now my current output is:

**The retailer details are [Krish,48, Danesh,47]**

But i want to get the **one list like [Krish,Danesh] .and [48,47] is separate another list**.How can i do ???

please give me solution ???

please give me a ideas to split the array list to separate list???

Comment: Use split method of string with your regular expression "," may be it help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

 Iterator<RetailerNames > retaileriterator = retailerNamesList.iterator();

while(retaileriterator.hasNext()){
 id=retaileriterator .next().getmRetailerid();
 System.out.println(id);
  list.add(id);
   }
 System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In my condition getLocationDetails return arraylist
and  LocationDetails is POJO same like your class RetailerNames 
Iterator<LocationDetails> it= getUserLocationsWrapper.getLocationDetails().iterator();
while(locationCitiDetailsItr.hasNext()){
locationCitiDetailsItr.next().getCity());
}
same i think  try this one
Iterator<RetailerNames > retaileriterator = retailerNamesList.iterator();
while(retaileriterator.hasNext()){
Object id=retaileriterator .next().getmRetailerid();
//add this id into another list
//same RetailerNames
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use nested array

Put [Krish,48] is one list and
[damesh,47] in another list and put both the list in one main array list

Comment: pls give me a solution yaar...i can;t get your point.so pls read my updated question and give me a solution yaar.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
   public class RetailerNames implements Serializable{


    private String mProductType;
    private String mRetailerid;

    public String getmProductType() {
        return mProductType;
    }

    public void setmProductType(String mProductType) {
        this.mProductType = mProductType;
    }

    public String getmRetailerid() {
        return mRetailerid;
    }

    public void setmRetailerid(String mRetailerid) {
        this.mRetailerid = mRetailerid;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  + mProductType + ","
                + mRetailerid +;  //Remove "[" this..
    }
```

And,

```
 ArrayList<RetailerNames> retailerNamesList = (ArrayList<RetailerNames>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("ProductsDetailsDescriptionPage");
        System.out.println("The retailer details are"+" "+retailerNamesList);
```

Now try

```
Object temp[]=retailerNamesList.toArray();
String[] values=temp.toString().split(",");

String names=values[0];
String names=values[1];
```

Comment: I have not test it.. please if there is any problem tell me.I haduse like this time ago .

Comment: String names=values[1]; here names is Duplicate local variable names.i gave another variable name like String names1=values[1] means am getting the following error:09-04 14:10:30.311: E/AndroidRuntime(11720): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
pls give me a solution yaar..

Comment: keep String names1=valuses[1] in comment and thn try and see o/p what is the result of String names=values[0]

Comment: this is my code:System.out.println("The retailer details are"+" "+retailerNamesList);
     Object temp[]=retailerNamesList.toArray();
     String[] values=temp.toString().split(",");
     System.out.println(values);
     String names=values[0];
        System.out.println(names);
     ...now am getting the output like:09-04 14:28:54.346: I/System.out(14061): The retailer details are [Krish,48, Danesh,47]
09-04 14:28:54.346: I/System.out(14061): [Ljava.lang.String;@41c01dd8
09-04 14:28:54.346: I/System.out(14061): [Ljava.lang.Object;@41b3cb50